# SlimDx Events on button pressed

Tags: c#, slimdx

I am using slimdx to interpret xbox controller button presses. I poll every 200ms to read the xbox button states and all works for me. I use

```
        JoystickState state = Joystick.GetCurrentState();
        // get buttons states
        bool[] buttonsPressed = state.GetButtons();
```

Is there anyway to generate events on the button press instead of polling? To explain imagine if my poll time was 5 seconds. And the user presses a button in the 2nd second and releases it. In the next poll time my application will never know that the button was pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - in DirectX you must poll. To do this efficiently you want to create a polling thread, and have a class which raises cross thread events to your consuming thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years old but the answer is incorrect.  The most efficient way may be to poll, but you can raise an event when you poll.

This is a work in progress but it should get someone started.  Save this as a new class, it derives from a Timer, so once you add this to your project, build it, and drag it onto the Form you want to use it, you can then subscribe to the buttonPressed event.

```
public class GamePadController : Timer
{

    public delegate void ButtonPressedDelegate(object sender, int ButtonNumber);
    public event ButtonPressedDelegate ButtonPressed;

    List<DeviceInstance> directInputList = new List<DeviceInstance>();
    DirectInput directInput = new DirectInput();
    List<SlimDX.DirectInput.Joystick> gamepads = new List<Joystick>();
    SlimDX.DirectInput.JoystickState state;



    public GamePadController()
    {
        this.Interval = 10;
        this.Enabled = true;
        this.Tick += GamePadController_Tick;
        RefreshGamePads();
        
    }


    private void RefreshGamePads()
    {
        directInputList.Clear();
        directInputList.AddRange(directInput.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameController, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly));
        gamepads.Clear();
        foreach (var device in directInputList)
        {
            gamepads.Add(new SlimDX.DirectInput.Joystick(directInput, directInputList[0].InstanceGuid));
        }
    }

    private void GamePadController_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        foreach (var gamepad in gamepads)
        {
            if (gamepad.Acquire().IsFailure)
                continue;
            if (gamepad.Poll().IsFailure)
                continue;
            if (SlimDX.Result.Last.IsFailure)
                continue;

            state = gamepad.GetCurrentState();

            bool[] buttons = state.GetButtons();

            for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (buttons[i])
                {
                    if (ButtonPressed != null)
                    {
                        ButtonPressed(gamepad, i);
                    }
                }
            }

            gamepad.Unacquire();
        }

    }
}
}
```